# Filtering to (blank) rows in Google Sheets using Google API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, filter

I am writing a function that will filter a date column to only the blank rows.

I started with creating a macro but the macro will select every existing date entry (at the time of the macro being created) and only filter those dates. The problem being this is an active spreadsheet with new dates added daily. I've tried this using .newFilterCriteria but that will automatically filter the row when the date is added (not preferable because there is more data to be entered when the date is entered). So I would like to write a function that uses .setHiddenValues to any and all dates which would only show the rows that are blank. My question is, how do I write that criterion using .setHiddenValues or using a different method? Thanks.

```
function Blankexample() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('G1').activate();
  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
 .setHiddenValues(['All Dates Here'])
 .build();
 spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(7, criteria);
};
```

Comment: _ I have some onEdit functions running on this sheet as well that I think are causing a problem. When I use .whenCellEmpty, my sheet will recalculate the filter before all the data can be entered into the row; that is why I was trying the .setHiddenValues route._ You didn't mention `onEdit` in your question (let alone, "onEdit functions"- FWIW, multiple onEdit is a recipe for chaos). May I respectfully suggest that you need to edit your question to describe your scenario, and create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```
  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
                               .whenCellEmpty()
                               .build();
```

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter-criteria-builder#whencellempty

Comment: That works on my test sheet with no other scripts running. I have some onEdit functions running on this sheet as well that I think are causing a problem. When I use .whenCellEmpty, my sheet will recalculate the filter before all the data can be entered into the row; that is why I was trying the .setHiddenValues route.